Weird IPv6 issue on Windows Server DNS, on an IPv4 network
All of a sudden, systems can not resolve any local hostnames. They are using just this one DNS server right now, the domain's primary, and can resolve addresses for hosts not on the internal domain, but not hosts on the internal domain. Not even the DNS server itself can resolve internal hosts.
The work around seems to be point the IPv6 DNS at the server (which has an automatic address, or in the case of that server is loopback), or disable IPv6 in the NIC properties. This will bandage the issue on any system including the server.
I have tried disabling v6 on the servers NIC, and I have gone in to the DNS server settings and told it to listen only on the v4 address. If I disable v6 on the server's NIC, the clients need to all have v6 disabled.
I've tried to do some searching around but to be honest I'm not too sure how to word this to get the search that I am asking for.
